# Inserting/Updating Oracle LONG field using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am dealing with a legacy application and the database is in Oracle. One of the field in the table is LONG (it's deprecated in new versions of Oracle) to store large amount of Text data. But the issue is whenever I try to insert to this table nhibernate hungs at ExecuteNonQuery. What I figured out is I need to find the right 'type' while configuring the field in hbm file. If I commented the below configuration from hbm file and run the test then every thing works fine. I use ODP.NET to connect to Oracle db.

`<property name="TextData" column="TEXT_DATA" not-null="false" access="property" type="dont know what's nhibernate type equivalent to Oracle LONG"/>`

In my entity TextData is a string property.

My question here is how to deal with an Oracle column with Type LONG via NHibernate?

Regards,

Sony Arouje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding a custom type derived from IUserType. You can find the implementation in my [post](http://sonyarouje.com/2012/11/07/nhibernate-and-oracle-long-varchar-field/)